# Easter egg puzzle

Tags: computer-puzzle

A friend of mine sent me a puzzle which has eggs labeled with numbers 76 95 228 361 158 171.
The puzzle is asking, which egg doesn't belong in the nest.
All of the eggs have different colors too which might matter:

[image]

I tried a bunch of different conversions with the numbers, because the puzzle is supposed to be programming related, but got nothing so far.

Comment: was it sent as numeric file or paper ? the numeric representation of colors might be relevant

Comment: It's a paper, so I guess we can only estimate the color numeric representations.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

As a go player, it was a lot easier to recognise the big egg for what it was, and from there, it’s easy to see that

> $158\ \ (= 2 \times 79)$

is the odd one out. That’s because all the other numbers are

> divisible by 19. In more detail:
>  $76 = 19 \times 4$,
>  $95 = 19 \times 5$,
>  $171 = 19 \times 9$,
>  $228 = 19 \times 12$, and finally
>  $361 = 19 \times 19$, the size of the regular go board.

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by "recognizing the big egg for what it was"?

Comment: A Go board is 19x19. At the end of a game the players must count the size of their territories. A Go player will be very familiar with the multiples of 19. The "big egg" is the size of the full board 19x19.

Answer (score 5):

I believe its:

> the red 361 egg, since 361 > 255 and therefore requires more than one byte, and we all know eggs are bite-sized! (byte-sized?)

Comment: You must have a large mouth... eggs are about 2 large bites

Answer (score 2):

> 171 Is out, adding its digits together is less then 10, all others are greater than 10

Comment: Technically 361 isn't _greater than_ but I see where you're coming from.